# Bootstrap & jQuery - Toggle Div based on Bootstrap Dropdown Menu open or close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show a div when Bootstrap Dropdown opens and hide the same when dropdown closes...

---

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wy1xL1Lb/2/)

---

> **HTML**

---

```
<ul class="dropdown" id="flatmenu">
  <li data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><a href="#">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
  <div class="dropdown-menu fm-container" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    Dropdown Content
  </div>
</ul>


<div class="show-me">Show Me</div>
```

> **CSS**

---

```
body{width:400px;margin:50px auto;}
ul,li{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
.show-me{display:none;margin-top:200px;}
```

> **jQuery**

---

```
if($('#flatmenu').hasClass('open')){
    $('.show-me').show('slow');
}else{
    $('.show-me').hide('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [bootstrap-docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events):

```
$('#flatmenu').on('shown.bs.dropdown hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
  $('.show-me').toggle('slow');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8zwLhunk/)

Comment: Perfect empiric... Thank you somuch

Answer (score 1):

You could do [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) for the element that it's intended for and use the [`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) effect for the `div` that is going to show/hide instead.

Code snippet:

```
$("#flatmenu").click(function () {
    $('.show-me').toggle('slow');
});
```

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wy1xL1Lb/3/)

Comment: @ urbz, Thanks for the Answer ... But in this case, if I click outside of dropdown, div also should close with Dropdown... which is not happening in your expample... Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can try this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wy1xL1Lb/4/)

Code:

```
$('#flatmenu').on('click',function(){
    $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($this.hasClass('open')){
            $('.show-me').show('slow');
        }else{
            $('.show-me').hide('slow');
        }
    },100);
});
```

Comment: @ Amit, Thanks for your reply... if I click outside of dropdown, div also should close with Dropdown... like "empiric's" solution